# How do I show this inequality that $\frac{\ln({x+1})}{\ln({x})} \leq \frac{x}{x-1}$ for $x>1$?

Tags: inequality, logarithms

How do I show this inequality that for $x>1$ $$\frac{\ln({x+1})}{\ln({x})} \leq \frac{x}{x-1}$$

So far I have tried to use the inequality $\ln({x+1}) < x$, but it is not good enough.

Comment: For $x>1$, the inequality is equivalent to $\frac{\log(x+1)}{x} \le \frac{\log(x)}{x-1}$. Consider a decreasing function $f(x) = \frac{\log(x+1)}{x}$ .

Answer (score 4):

You can show it using concavity of $\ln x$ as follows:

The given inequality is equivalent to

$$\ln x \geq \frac{x-1}{x}\ln(x+1)$$

Now, since $x>1$ we have

$$\frac{x-1}{x}\ln(x+1) + \frac 1x\ln 1 \stackrel{concavity}{\leq}\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x}(x+1) +\frac 1x\cdot 1\right) =\ln x$$

Done.

Comment: Nice solution, sometimes the answer is easy

Comment: @question : Thanks for your appreciation :-)

Answer (score 1):

For $x>1$
$$x\ln x -(x-1)\ln(x+1)
=\int_1^x \int_t^\infty \frac{u-1}{u(u+1)^2}\>dudt\ge0$$
Rearrange the inequality to obtain

$$\frac{\ln({x+1})}{\ln x} \leq \frac{x}{x-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, show you work and explain what you've tried.)

**Hint:** Prove that $(x+1)^{x-1} < x^x $ for $ x > 1$.

**Further hint:** Direct application of weighted AM-GM.

**Corollary:** Inequality as stated, after taking logarithms.